# glUniforms() and [] operator overloading woes

Tags: c++, opengl, pointers, reference

I'm having some issues getting the following code to compile:

```
GLint iModelMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(m_shaderProgramID, "mvMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(iModelMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, &myMatrix[0]);

GLint iLight = glGetUniformLocation(m_shaderProgramID, "vLightPos");
glUniform3fv(iLight, 1, &myVector[0]);
```

Now myMatrix and myVector are two objects, each of these classes have the [] operator overloaded as follows:

```
inline float& operator[](int index)     { return m_data[index]; }
inline float  operator[](int index) const   { return m_data[index]; }
```

I receive the following error:

```
error C2102: '&' requires l-value
```

I'm trying to udnerstand why '&' requires a left hand side value? I've passed data like this before. Arent I simply giving the address to the first index of the m_data array? Doesn't that constitute as a float*?

Why does it not satisfy the function specification?

```
void glUniformMatrix4fv(GLint location, GLsizei count, GLboolean transpose, const GLfloat *value);
```

EDIT:

alright it seems that because im passing these objects as const refereneces to the function that makes the above calls, it is passing the float* arrays by value, and thus i can't reference them.

I tried adding a third [] operator:

```
inline const float& operator[](int index) const    { return m_data[index]; }
```

But that made my compiler explode. Is there a reason why i cannot do this?

Comment: How are `myMatrix` and `myVector` declared? (Are they `const`?)

Comment: hmmm now that you mention it they are passed as const references to the function that makes these calls... that may be the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
inline float  operator[](int index) const   { return m_data[index]; }
```

should be *converted* into this:

```
inline const float &operator[](int index) const   { return m_data[index]; }
```

if you want to take the address of the return value. You don't add a third version; you *change* the current one into this. You can't take the address of a temporary, but you can take the address of a `const&`.

Personally, I think you should have a specialzed function that just returns a `float*` or `const float*`, much like C++11 did with [std::vector::data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data). That way, you just call `myMatrix.data()` rather than having to do a `&...[0]` kludge. It's self-documenting and obvious.

Answer (score -2):

Just store the result of `operator[]` in a local variable:

```
float tmp = myMatrix[0];
glUniformMatrix4fv(iModelMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, &tmp);
```

This avoids unnamed temporary that cannot be treated as l-value.

Comment: -1: That's pretty wrong. `glUniformMatrix4fv` takes an array of at least 16 floats. You're passing it an array of *one* float.

Comment: Maybe, but that would the *semantics* of the function being used, not the rules of the language. The question was about l-value error. You found more problems with the original code - great. Still don't see a reason to downvote.

Comment: The OP asked for a way to get the *array* stored in `myMatrix`. He did not ask for a way to get a float. Thus, even ignoring the fact that the code you gave is broken, *it doesn't answer the question*. Context is important.